# Updating Object's values inside an object with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

Having tough time trying to update just the "values" property which is a object within an object. I am not super familiar with the reactjs or its shenanigans.

```
const [properties, setProperties] = useState({})

<Form.Control onChange={e => setProperties(prevState => ({...prevState, values: {a: value}}))}>
<Form.Control onChange={e => setProperties(prevState => ({...prevState, values: {b: value}}))}>
```

Final object should look like this:

```
{ 
  x: 1, <-- These have their  
  y: 2, <-- own inputs
  values: { 
    a: "A value", 
    b: "B value" 
  }
}
```

But currently after typing to one the inputs value A overrides B or vice-versa. I tried searching answers from web, but none concerned updating object's object

Answer (score 6):

You're close. You have to spread the nested objects properties back into it just like you did with `prevState`.

```js
setProperties(prevState => ({...prevState, values: {...prevState.values, b: e.target.value}}))
```

Spreading `prevState` makes a new object out of its values. But when you specify a key to overwrite the values taken from `prevState` are gone. Basically, you aren't merging `prevState.values` with the new `values`. You're overwritting it.

To fix this you need to provide the whole nested object again. The easiest pattern for that is the one above. Spread `prevState.values`, then overwrite the nested key you want to change.

**Note:** If you use an event in a functional update, you need to either save the value to another variable, or use `e.persist()` first. The reason is that React reuses event objects for performance reasons, so `e` will be reset before the async update happens. using `persist` removes the event from the pool for reuse, and you may access its values normally.

Example:

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
  e.persist();
  setProperties(prevState => (
    {
      ...prevState, 
      values: {...prevState.values, b: e.target.value}
    }
  ))

  // OR

  let value = e.target.value;
  setProperties(prevState => (
    {
      ...prevState, 
      values: {...prevState.values, b: value}
    }
  ))
}
```

As another note, I only used a functional update in my answer because that is how the question was given. But in this usecase it is not required. You may use a normal state update safely for this handler.

Comment: Thank You Brian, Did you mean this?: onChange={e => setProperties(prevState => ({...prevState.values, values: {a: e.target.value}}))}. This results into an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Yeah that seems right. I copied it directly from the question, I didn't pay attention to the missing `e.target`.

Comment: Hello Brian, This method is invalid. For some reason e.target.value appears to be null. Thus the error mentioned before. I read somewhere that you have to use persist() method on the particular event, if you want your method to work.

Comment: It's not my method. I just copied it from your question. The solution I gave is not invalid. The solution I provided was that you need to replace all object values that you overwrite. In your question you claimed that it was updating one value but losing the other. This is the update pattern to fix it. If you use the functional update, yes you need to use `e.persist()` before the code I gave. This is because React reuses event objects for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The new state is not computed using old values, so you don't need to pass a function to `setProperties`. Instead, you can write it simply like this:

```
const [properties, setProperties] = useState({})

<Form.Control onChange={e => setProperties({ ...properties, values: { ...properties.values, a: e.target.value }})}>
<Form.Control onChange={e => setProperties({ ...properties, values: { ...properties.values, b: e.target.value }})}>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great – happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, {
    useState
} from "react";


function Test() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
            x: 1, 
            y: 2, 
            values: { 
              a: "A value", 
              b: "B value" 
            }
    });
    const changeA = (e) => {
        const val = e.target.value;
        setState({...state, a: val})
    }
    const changeB = (e) => {
        const val = e.target.value;
        setState({...state, b: val})
    }
    return (
         <div>
           <input onChange={changeA}/>
           <input onChange={changeB}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test;
```